# Is it possible to harden systemd below 7.0 if my package needs permissions to install other packages?

Tags: debian, systemd, packaging, hardening

I am not sure if my question has a proper answer but I still wanted to try.

I want to harden my app systemd, the problem is that my package needs permissions to install other packages (that is one of the most problematic things I guess).

I was able to drop my rating to around 7.0 with among others: `NoNewPrivileges`, various `ProtectKernel`, `ProtectHome`, `ProtectProc`, `ProtectClock` and some others.

The thing is, I am not able to use "the most powerful" entrys like `PrivateTmp`, `ProtectSystem`, `PrivateDevices`, `MemoryDenyWriteExecute`, `ProtectHostname`, `LockPersonality`.

I am wondering, If my hands are tied without the entrys above and I should simply harden my package with other methods or I can still do something more with systemd?

Thanks!